# Get 'creation_time' of video using ffmpeg and regex

Tags: c#, regex, ffmpeg

I have a **metadata** text of a video file which is produced by **ffmpeg**.

```
Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2011-09-10 21:44:22
    model           : iPhone 4
    model-deu       : iPhone 4
    encoder         : 4.3.5
    encoder-deu     : 4.3.5
    date            : 2011-09-10T17:44:22-0400
    date-deu        : 2011-09-10T17:44:22-0400
    location        : +40.7329-073.9864/
    location-deu    : +40.7329-073.9864/
    make            : Apple
    make-deu        : Apple
```

I want to get the ***'creation_time'*** value using **regex** of the above text. I am using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use next regex pattern:

```
creation_time\s*:\s*(\d+-\d+-\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)
```

or more specific pattern:

```
creation_time\s*:\s*(\d{1,4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})
```

subpattern return a creation date