# Get 'location' of video using ffmpeg and regex

Tags: c#, regex, ffmpeg

I have a metadata text of a video file which is produced by **ffmpeg**.

```
Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2011-09-10 21:44:22
    model           : iPhone 4
    model-deu       : iPhone 4
    encoder         : 4.3.5
    encoder-deu     : 4.3.5
    date            : 2011-09-10T17:44:22-0400
    date-deu        : 2011-09-10T17:44:22-0400
    location        : +40.7329-073.9864/
    location-deu    : +40.7329-073.9864/
    make            : Apple
    make-deu        : Apple
```

What **regex** i need to write if I want to get the *'location'* value from above text. I am using C#.

Comment: Do you think to ask questions for all tabs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572221/get-creation-time-of-video-using-ffmpeg-and-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use next regex pattern:

```
location\s*:\s*(+\d+\.\d+-\d+.\d+\/)
```

subpattern return a location

Or try this:

```
location\s*:\s*(\+\d+\.\d+-\d+.\d+\/)
```

Comment: may be you should change the 'creation_time' tag @Victor

Comment: Yes, need to change to `location`

Comment: Exception: parsing "location\s*:\s*(+\d+\.\d+-\d+.\d+\/)" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing. @Victor

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you need to use should be:

`location[ ]+:[ ]+([0-9+-\.)\/`

This should work with any regular expression engine. Once you get the coordinates, skip the first sign (plus or minus) and split on the second sign.

Victor's answer is almost correct with two important points:

- Not all regex engines support \s
- The location may start with minus and might contain less digits; -40+73 is a valid location which will not match the answer above.